# Raphaeljs: accessing the relative postion of a click on a closed path

Tags: javascript, ajax, raphael

i'm using the excellent raphaeljs library and after having created a path with

```
var c = paper.path("M10 10L90 90 ..... z");
```

i would like to get the position of the click event on the path relative to the canvas.
I tried:

```
c.click(function (event) {
   alert(event.pageX);
}));
```

but that gives me a value which is not relative to raphael's canvas.
Any idea?
thx

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
var x = Math.floor((event.pageX-$("#paper").offset().left));
```

Obviously this is using jQuerys $ to get the paper element..

Comment: Be aware that offset() can be expensive, so you may want an intermediate variable if using both left and top.