# Raphael.js how to find click position on a path?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Is there any way to access a click-on-path coordinates? And one other: is possible to find out whitch is the previous closest corner on the path?

I was read this, but not so helpful:
[Raphaeljs: accessing the relative postion of a click on a closed path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146133/raphaeljs-accessing-the-relative-postion-of-a-click-on-a-closed-path)

Thanks for yout time!

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 400, 400);

var path = paper.path("M0 0L10 100L50 100L100 70").attr({"stroke": "#000", "stroke-width": "3"});
path.click(function(event) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(event.x, event.y);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLmHd/2/

### Edit

I only made a start for you. This is a way, not the only way.

I created an object with 2 arrays. x and y.

Every click I add the point. (You need to check on what index you want to push the point)
Also you need to check what the closes corner is. [This could be helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881609/finding-the-closest-number-in-a-random-set)

I hope this will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/fvtPN/

Comment: Thx, this is get back the click position! Cool. And how to find out what is the previous corner position?

Comment: actually, I want to insert an other breakpoint into the path where the user clicked.

Comment: You asked for how to get click position on a path, you got that then asked more questions, you should accept this answer first then raise a new question.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right.  If I click at the very very end of the path, it returns coordinates of like (109,80) when I can see I am within 2 maybe 3 pixels of the ending coordinates of (100,70).  Why is it off by almost 10 pixels in both directions?